# How do I Log the Class file without the path in log4net

Tags: configuration, logging, log4net

I want to be able to log the class file and line number in my log file so I am using the following config...

```
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <!--etc-->
   <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
       <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level (%file:%line) %logger => %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

However the %file attribute is making my log file entries waaaay too long to read comfortably....

```
2009-08-07 16:41:55,271 [7] INFO  (O:\mystream\aevpallsrv\DotNet\com.mycompany.au\myapp\Myappp\Controller.cs:75) MyApp.Controller => Controller.EnqueueWorkerThreads() - START
```

Is there a way to show just the class file ('Controller.cs') instead of the full path to the file also???

Michael

Answer (score 6):

Although you're asking about the file name, I believe you can use ***%type*** to get the fully qualified type name (a.b.className).  If you just want the class name, use ***%type{1}***

Note that any method that generates caller information (%file and %type) have a performance cost associated with them.

As an aside, you can bypass the performance hit by naming the Logger using the Type name.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{     
    public class Foo
    {
        private static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Foo));
    }
}
```

Your conversion pattern would look like:

```
"%date [%thread] %-5level %logger %message"
```

Where your logger would be "*MyNameSpace.Foo*".  Likewise, if you only want the class name, use "*%logger{1}*, which will resolve as "*Foo*".

One of the best advantages to this approach is that you can leverage log4net's hierarchical repository system to adjust logging levels per type:

```
<!-- all classes in MyNamespace are warn -->
<logger name="MyNamespace">
     <level value="WARN" />
</logger>

<!-- only Foo is in debug -->
<logger name="MyNamespace.Foo">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
</logger>
```

Comment: I haven't tried, but I wonder what %file{1} would work that same way that %type{1} would?

Comment: Thanks for that Bryan.  I am using the type name as the logger name and this works ok.  I found that the class and line number information didn't work with my 'Release' configuration files anyway (I didn't release the pdb file) so I am skipping these entirely for my production release.

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, PatternLayout supports only the %file token. What you can do is subclass PatternLayout and add your own pattern, say %filename, and for this token only output the name of the file.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I really didn't want to mess around with subclassing in Log4Net but I suppose I will give it a go.  While I'm there, I might try and customise the stoopid file naming options of the RollingLogFileAppender.

Comment: Go for it. Adding your own patterns to Patternlayout is actually quite easy... let us all know how it goes.